# Xpages sorting date

Tags: sorting, xpages

I'm stuck with sorting and showing the correct date in Xpages.
It is saved in format "dd.MM.yyyy" and it's a string.

Now why it's a string and formated that way, is because my boss has special wishes. And when I want to sort it from the newest date to older it does something like this:

```
26.05.2015
24.06.2014
22.04.2015
21.04.2015
20.03.2014
```

It starts sorting by day.

**Is there a way to make it sort it like it should?**

I see that i can write a Computed value to Sort column in view column header for date. But i don't know how to even start.

Comment: Don't store the date as a string. Store it as a date and then apply formatting afterwards in the UI.

Comment: It is the same problem with the date type

Comment: I am unclear where and how you want to display the data.  Is this in a view column as part of a view control?

Comment: If you're doing something like _@Text(DateField)_ for your column value, then it will always be only text (and exhibit the sort of behavior you're noticing). If you instead ensure the [column's data type](https://twitter.com/edm00se/status/577818709705826304) to be a date (NotesDateTime), it knows how to sort ascending/descending. The only thing left after that is for you to apply formatting when you _display_ the date, not when  you store or load its text value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the underlying Notes view to get your date column into right order.

Convert the date strings to real date values in views column formula. Assuming your field is called `DateText` then your formula would be

```
@Date(@ToNumber(@Right(DateText; 4)); 
      @ToNumber(@Middle(DateText; 3; 2)); 
      @ToNumber(@Left(DateText; 2)))
```

It would be easier to use just `@ToTime(DateText)` but this can fail depending on server's local settings. Your date string format would work for a server with German locale settings but not for US. That's why is my suggested solution "safer".

Answer (score 0):

If the date time value doesn't solve your problem and you do not transform your date via @Text (as mentioned in the comments) then create another (hidden) column BEFORE your column that should be displayed. Make this a true date (from your item), sort it and unsort the column to display.

Otherwise use this formula in the newly created sorted column:

```
@Text(@Year(yourDate))+"-"+@Right("00"+@Text(@Month(yourDate));2)+"-"+@Right("00"+@Text(@Day(yourDate));2)
```